# Is there a law that regulates charging an online account to which the owner has no access?

Tags: united-states, internet, online, indiana, credit-card

Is it legal for an online service to charge an account holder credit card for services that are contingent on the account holder being able to manage their account if the account holder's access has been restricted?

Comment: "...access has been restricted." Restricted by who?

Comment: Restricted by the company providing the online service.

Comment: Just a note: If one were to assume that the company was acting in bad faith, one would also have to assume that their legal department was in on it. To challenge that, you would need a **real** lawyer from the applicable jurisdictions, not just bits and pieces from the web to put into a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what terms of service the account holder signed up to.

For instance, one could run a website at a cloud provider, configure it so that it *automatically* scales up when the traffic grows, and then mishandle the credentials so that one cannot shut it down quickly. By the time access is restored, there might be quite some bill.

As it recently made the news, when a business deliberately makes it easier to *sign up* than to *cancel*, the [FTC](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/news/press-releases/2023/06/ftc-takes-action-against-amazon-enrolling-consumers-amazon-prime-without-consent-sabotaging-their) may step in. But that was an extreme case.

Comment: Is there a source where I can read about this ruling/action?

Comment: @LS, I linked their press release. It is rather recent, I expect the legal wrangling to take years.

Comment: Ok, this is the type of thing I am looking for.

Comment: @LS, and the link was in there yesterday. :-)